# Visual Studio Redeploy feature for BizTalk solution does not work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, biztalk, biztalk-2013

My BizTalk solution has 10 BizTalk projects that are referenced between each other.
In each project's properties I have set redeploy feature to 'true' (it's by default).

But when I try to redeploy the whole solution from VS 2012, I get following errors for some projects in solution:

> Error 201 Failed to add resource(s). Change requests failed for some
>   resources. BizTalkAssemblyResourceManager failed to complete end type
>   change request. Cannot update assembly "Project1, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral" because it is used by assemblies which are not in the
>   set of assemblies to update. To update the assembly, remove the
>   following assemblies: Project2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral
>   Project3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral Project4, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral Project5, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral Project6,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

As I read from this article:
http://blog.codit.eu/post/2013/07/30/Redeployment-notes-of-a-BizTalk-solution-from-Visual-studio.aspx

> In the process of deploying a BizTalk assembly, you first needed to
>   manually stop, unenlist, and unbind artifacts contained in the
>   assembly in BizTalk Server and then remove the assembly from the
>   BizTalk Management (configuration) database before deployment. Visual
>   Studio will handle all those steps for you with this option Redeploy.

What could be the reason of my problem and possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you use subfolders in your solution.

I suggest to create new (additional) solution just for deployment purpose where you should avoid to use any solution subfolders

Andrei

Comment: Awesome! I am really using solution subfolders... You helped me a lot and saves me a lot of days! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check that one of the assemblies hasn't gone into the Default Application rather than the application you are deploying too.  If you find one in the wrong place you can right click it and select Move to Application. (The other option is to remove it, but then quite often you have to remove all the dependent ones as well).

Check each project that the Application is set.

Then re-deploy.

This happens quite often, especially if you just got a project down from source control, as the Application is saved in the user file rather than the project file.

Edit: Also check your solution setting to make sure all projects have deploy ticked.

Comment: For each project application name is set and there are no artifacts in default application. For some reason visual studio can not delete dependent assemblies and asks me to do it before I click 'deploy'. That is strange...

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting the temp binding files at: C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\Deployment\BindingFiles

Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the configuration manager for solution if any project is not marked for deployment. Right click on solution then select Configuration Manager and make sure all projects are selected for deploy,

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is some problem with BizTalk 2016 party export/import that prohibits re-import of bindings during deploy from Visual Studio.

My workaround is to export bindings manually before deploy, and manually import bindings after "successful" deploy (cited from the deploy log in visual studio ;).

Other reference:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c49758c0-0465-4c13-97a3-300c05d00d3a/biztalk-2016-redeploy-and-orchestration-bindings?forum=biztalkgeneral&prof=required